# CSS fixed on top bar must remain on left

Tags: css, html, css-position

I'm currently finishing up some things up on my website, however I've noticed a problem.
I have an top bar menu which has the position fixed.

The body and both the header have a minimum width of 1150 to prevent the layout becoming buggy (Primairly because of the admin section).

But it seems that the fixed position is not only make sure it would stick to the top, but also to the left.

Is there anyway to make the bar stick to the top, but not to the left so it could still scroll from the left to the right to make sure I could see the other menu items?

Live Preview: http://www.evesaints.com

Just resize the window and note that when you slide to the right, the menu will move too, instead of sticking to the left.

Kind Regards,
Larssy1

---

I prefer a CSS-only solution, I do know how to fix it with JQuery, but I consider it nasty.

---

To preview the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Jm297/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    <img src="http://www.evesaints.com/images/header.png" alt="EVE Probing Tracker" title="EVE Probing Tracker">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="http://www.evesaints.com/overview/">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.evesaints.com/news/">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.evesaints.com/how_to_play/">How to play?</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.evesaints.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="http://www.ignitecoding.com">
        <img src="http://www.evesaints.com/images/ignite_header.png" alt="IgniteCoding" title="IgniteCoding">
    </a>
    <ul id="menuAccount">
        <li id="topBarIskContainer"><a href="#"><span id="topBarIskBalance">CURRENT BALANCE</span><br>57,515,000 ISK</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.evesaints.com/dashboard/">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.evesaints.com/logout/">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*
    RESET
*/
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: "arial";
    font-size: 12px;
    z-index: 1;
}

html, body, #header {
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    min-width: 1145px;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 14px;
}

body {
    background: #1d1d1d;
}

input, select, textarea {
    padding: 5px;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
}

.ui-autocomplete-input {
    margin: 5px;
}

.quote {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #2b2b2b;
}

input[type="submit"],
input[type="button"] {
    background: #ff6633;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
}

#menu {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}

#menuAccount {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}

#header #menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#header #menu li a:link,
#header #menu li a:hover,
#header #menu li a:active,
#header #menu li a:visited,
#header #menu li a:focus {
    display: block;
    padding: 18px;
    color: #1d1d1d;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header #menu li a:hover,
#header #menu li a:active {
    background-color: #ff6633;
    color: #fff;
}

#header #menuAccount > li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#header #menuAccount li a:link,
#header #menuAccount li a:hover,
#header #menuAccount li a:active,
#header #menuAccount li a:visited,
#header #menuAccount li a:focus {
    display: block;
    padding: 18px;
    background-color: #ff6633;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header #menuAccount #topBarIskContainer a:link,
#header #menuAccount #topBarIskContainer a:hover,
#header #menuAccount #topBarIskContainer a:active,
#header #menuAccount #topBarIskContainer a:visited,
#header #menuAccount #topBarIskContainer a:focus {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    background: none;
    color: #1d1d1d;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: default;
    text-align: center;
}
#header #menuAccount #topBarIskContainer #topBarIskBalance {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#header #menuAccount li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 51px;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ff6633;
}
#header #menuAccount ul li:hover {
    background: #f9f9f9;
}
#header #menuAccount ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
#header #menuAccount ul li a:link,
#header #menuAccount ul li a:active,
#header #menuAccount ul li a:visited,
#header #menuAccount ul li a:focus {
    float: left;
    background: none !important;
    color: #1d1d1d !important;
}
#header #menuAccount ul li a:hover {
    background: #f1f1f1;
}
#header #menuAccount ul {
    display: none;
    z-index: 5;
}
#header {
    background: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ff6633;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
#header a:link img {
    border: none;
    margin: 10px;
}
#header a:link,
#header a:hover,
#header a:active,
#header a:visited,
#header a:focus {
    /*position: absolute;
    right: 0px;*/
    float: right;
}

#header > img {
    margin: 9px;
    float: left;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #ff6633;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
}

h2 a:link,
h2 a:hover,
h2 a:focus,
h2 a:visited,
h2 a:active {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
}

p {
    margin: 8px 0;
}

input {
    width: 266px;
}

a:link,
a:hover,
a:active,
a:visited,
a:focus {
    color: #ff6633;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.ui-button {
    width: 97px;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 960px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -115px;
}
```

Comment: css...html....anything for us to refer???

Comment: Thats why I added the live preview.. http://www.evesaints.com/

Comment: @larssy1 its customary to post your code in the question even if you include a live preview.

Comment: @leemo Ah alright, thought we be better to include just the webpreview because it would give a total image. I'll paste it into JSFiddle,, wouldn't change anything on the layout though.

Comment: I think it is not possible without JQuery

Comment: code added to the question.

Comment: I am not threatening. You added a wrong tag which wasted my time .Also I answered becoz of your wrong tag and you are giving my answer -1 even after your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Write a media query in CSS file at the bottom

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
   #header {
     position: absolute;
   }
}
```

This way it stays when screen is resized.
Change the max width to value you desire.
But then again it may not stay to the top

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `width 100%` from the `header` and add `left` and `right` as `0` then make `margin:0 auto`

```
#header {
background: #fff;
height: 50px;
border-bottom: 3px solid #ff6633;
margin-bottom: 20px;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0;
width: auto;
min-width: 1150px;
z-index: 9999;
margin: 0 auto;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Just curious, but why use `margin: 0 auto` if the header is 100% width? Even more curious, why would you use it on an element with `display: inline-block`?

Comment: Have you tested this?? When changing and adding the new lines in Google Chrome, I don't see any change.,, Not working in the JSFiddle.

Comment: Try change the css on your site in Google Chrome browser-> inspect element